# Syntax error C2059 when building building C application using C/C++ DLL header

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll

I'm attempting to translate a C++ DLL header file into a C/C++ compatible header. While I've gotten most of the major constructs in, I'm running into one last compiler issue I can't seem to explain. The following code works fine in C++ but when I attempt to compile a C application which just includes this file I get errors for my function definitions in my header file.

Code.h:

```
typedef void *PVOID;
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
#define WINAPI  __stdcall

#ifdef LIB_EXPORTS
    #define LIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define LIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

struct ToolState
{
    HANDLE DriverHandle;
    HANDLE Mutex;
    int LockEnabled;
    int Type;
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

(LIB_API) int SetRate(ToolState *Driver, int rate);

(LIB_API) void EnableLock(ToolState *Driver) ;

(LIB_API) int SendPacket(ToolState *Driver, unsigned char *OutBuffer, int frameSize);

//These also give me the same error:
//LIB_API WINAPI int SendPacket(ToolState *Driver, unsigned char *OutBuffer, int frameSize);
//__declspec(dllimport) WINAPI int SendPacket(ToolState *Driver, unsigned char *OutBuffer, int frameSize);

//Original C++ call that works fine with C++ but has multiple issues in C
//LIB_API int SetRate(ToolState *Driver, int rate);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Errors:

```
error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
error C2059: syntax error : 'type'
```

Google searching hasn't generated any relevant results. The following threads were close but don't exactly answer my question:

[C2059 syntax error using declspec macro for one function; compiles fine without it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7948417/c2059-syntax-error-using-declspec-macro-for-one-function-compiles-fine-without)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/117687/en-us

Why is this syntax error occuring?

Comment: Remove the `()` around `(LIB_API)` and try again.

Comment: That causes more errors:
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
error C2059: syntax error : ')'

Comment: Sorry I jumped the gun on you. You are right. Once I implemented the answer below I ran into another issue that was fixed by removing the parenthesis. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, structs are not types, so you must use `struct Foo` and `enum Bar` where in C++ you are able to use `Foo` and `Bar`.

Notes:

- In C++, you can still use the old syntax even when the type is a class.
- In C, people often use `typedef struct Foo Foo` which allows the same syntax as in C++ then.

Comment: Upticked, Matt, you will likely incur a minimal hit by the latter method mentioned here, `typedef struct ToolState {....} ToolState;` the rest of the code should require no changes beyond that if you're using the same MS toolchain for both C and C++ compilation.

Comment: Thank you both of you. I appreciate the extra notes and suggestions. They were very helpful. Everything works now. :)